# Tracking a name-changing branch in GitHub with CodePipeline

Tags: node.js, git, amazon-web-services, github, aws-codepipeline

I'm using CodePipeline to deploy automatically to EB my Node.JS app. I'm using also GitHub as my repo source.

Using Git Flow, every time I want to do a release, I have to create a branch called "release/x.y.z".

Is there any way that CodePipeline can track any branch that starts with or contains "release"? Maybe a wildcard like "release/*"? That way I can create a new release and don't have to set up a new pipeline or edit the existing one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodePipeline can currently only run on a single branch per source action which is defined in the action configuration. You need to specify a git repository and branch name when you create a pipeline, so if a branch name is unknown like GitFlow branching model, it is not possible to create a pipeline in advance.

CodePipeline tied to a single git branch is more of a feature of CodePipeline as the design is more inclined towards Trunk based development. Also, as per the designers of this service, CodePipeline is designed for post-merge/release validation. That is, once your change is ready to be released to production and is merged into your master/main branch, CodePipeline takes over and automatically tests and releases the final merged set of changes. CodePipeline has a lot of features like stage locking, superseding versions, etc. which don't work well for the case where you want to test a change in isolation before it's merged (e.g. feature branch testing or pull request testing.) Therefore currently there isn't a recommended way to do this in CodePipeline.

I would like to refer you to following blog posts which provide solutions that you may find useful for your use-case:

[Implementing GitFlow Using AWS CodePipeline, AWS CodeCommit, AWS CodeBuild, and AWS CodeDeploy](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/implementing-gitflow-using-aws-codepipeline-aws-codecommit-aws-codebuild-and-aws-codedeploy/)

[Multi-branch CodePipeline strategy with event-driven architecture](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/multi-branch-codepipeline-strategy-with-event-driven-architecture/)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you can't do this. You need one codepipeline for each branch you want to use.

If you want to set them up automatically, you need to develop a custom solution for that.